# Homebrew Gstreamer, Python and video

Tags: python, macos, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am trying to go through the Gstreamer tutorial, but I got stuck on the first two already ([1st](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=python), [2nd](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/concepts.html?gi-language=python)). Here is the copy of the 2nd lesson's code, for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import gi
import logging

gi.require_version("GLib", "2.0")
gi.require_version("GObject", "2.0")
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GLib, GObject


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="[%(name)s] [%(levelname)8s] - %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(sys.argv[1:])

# Create the elements
source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", "source")
sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink", "sink")

# Create the empty pipeline
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("test-pipeline")

if not pipeline or not source or not sink:
    logger.error("Not all elements could be created.")
    sys.exit(1)


# Build the pipeline
pipeline.add(source, sink)
if not source.link(sink):
    logger.error("Elements could not be linked.")
    sys.exit(1)

# Modify the source's properties
source.props.pattern = 0
# Can alternatively be done using `source.set_property("pattern",0)`
# or using `Gst.util_set_object_arg(source, "pattern", 0)`

# Start playing
ret = pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
    logger.error("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.")
    sys.exit(1)

# Wait for EOS or error
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS)

# Parse message
if msg:
    if msg.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug_info = msg.parse_error()
        logger.error(f"Error received from element {msg.src.get_name()}: {err.message}")
        logger.error(f"Debugging information: {debug_info if debug_info else 'none'}")
    elif msg.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        logger.info("End-Of-Stream reached.")
    else:
        # This should not happen as we only asked for ERRORs and EOS
        logger.error("Unexpected message received.")

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

If I run this code, the Python's rocket icon starts jumping on the Dock, but no video is shown. If I launch it with `GST_DEBUG=5 python3 02.py`, I can see the things happening and time ticking, just no video output.

When I run the 1st lesson's code, which creates a `playbin`, there is no Python rocket on the Dock; I hear the audio playing, but again, no video.

If I change the 2nd lesson's code (copied above) and make the `videotestsrc` and `autovideosink` into `audiotestsrc` and `autoaudiosink` (and comment out the `pattern` parameter), again, it works — I can hear the beep.

The Gstreamer command line tools work correctly, showing a video window for the equivalent pipelines:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=0 ! autovideosink
```

Any ideas why the Python version does not work correctly?

---

I have installed Gstreamer using `brew install gstreamer` (version: `stable 1.22.2 (bottled), HEAD`), with Python 3.11.3, on Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is nothing wrong with your python code. It is likely an issue with the element that is being selected by the `autovideosink`.

I've seen this happen with the `vaapisink`, where due to a bad GPU driver or just any incompatibility it can't display the window. You can determine which sink is selected by the `autovideosink` from running the pipeline with the verbose (`-v`) option.

If it is the vaapisink you can either uninstall the gstreamer vaapi elements (`apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi`) or trying to fix your installation. If it is another sink element you will need to debug that particular element installation or uninstall it. Once fixed or uninstalled `autovideosink` will use the fixed version or select another sink option that will likely work for you.

If you're just interested in the output and not necessarily making `autiovideosink` work you can  replace the `autovideosink` with another explicit video sink that you're sure works with your system, I recommend you try `xvimagesink` or `ximagesink`. That should display the `videotestsrc` properly.

Comment: 1. Note tag [tag:macos]: there is no `apt`. Everything is installed as part of the `gstreamer` formula; I cannot install or uninstall individual elements (unless, I suppose, I install from source). 2. `gst-launch-1.0` works; `python3 02.py` doesn't, and `-v` is not applicable there (it would debug Python, not Gstreamer). That said, replacing `autovideosink` with `ximagesink` or `glimagesink` worked. That still leaves me puzzled why automatic detection fails with Python bindings but not with `gst-launch-1.0`.

Comment: It would probably be good to open an issue about this, but I don't know whether it should be on the [Homebrew package](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues), on [Gstreamer](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/groups/gstreamer/-/issues) or on [Gst-Python](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-python/-/issues) tracker.

Comment: Huh, now `glimagesink` doesn't work; maybe I made a mistake. It shows the same rocket I was seeing before. `ximagesink` does work.

Comment: I forgot about you being in macos sorry. The only explanation I can think of regarding `autovideosink` working with `gst-launch-1.0` but not with python is that they are different versions and are launching different elements. Although this is unlikely since you haven't installed from source.
Interesting that it is not consistent. Does the `glimagesink` always work with `gst-launch-1.0`?
I'd suggest you enable the logs and make sure that both `gst-launch-1.0` and python are launching the same element inside `autovideosink`. You can also see this easily from the pipeline graph.

Comment: It seems `glimagesink` works from `gst-launch-1.0` but not from Python, so that might be the cause (but then, why does _that_ not work?). I am very new to Gstreamer so I don't know how to see what is happening inside `autovideosink`... Python's `gi.repository.Gst` is `<GstProxyModule <IntrospectionModule 'Gst' from '/usr/local/lib/girepository-1.0/Gst-1.0.typelib'>>`; that file is a softlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.22.2/lib/girepository-1.0/Gst-1.0.typelib`, and `brew ls -v gstreamer` shows that file is installed by the `gstreamer` package, just like `/usr/local/bin/gst-launch-1.0`.